# Get data from Groove Music using C#

Tags: c#, windows-10, rainmeter

I'm trying to fetch informations from Groove Music client like current track title, current track duration for a Rainmeter plugin wrote in C#.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to find a class which provides Groove Music client informations :/

The only thing i've found about SDK is a REST service which will not provide me those kind of information...

Does anybody know about it ?

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of info at https://music.microsoft.com/developer but you can get details for tracks from Groove pretty easily, you can do a search query using something like the example in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn546659.aspx the example for Daft Punk would return data for their albums but with the right parameters, you can do a track search - what exactly kind of information do you need and I'll edit this response with a few example calls for you later, I work with the Groove API as a third-party developer if that helps!

Comment: I'm not able to go on the Groove Music REST documentation. I've always a 502 gateway error.

By the way, what you're telling me is to use this API in order to get information about a "random" music in the world.

What I need is to get information about the track which is currently played by the desktop groove music application. More simply, how to know if the app is playing something and what it's playing.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get the currently playing track using the Groove Music API - you can get data on any track, album or artist on Groove that the app can also show but can't get that status, they're might be another way to do it, but don't think the Groove Music API will help - think of it as alternative of doing everything the app does with regards to music rather than integrating with the app